# Time series Moving average model

Tags: time-series

After a lot of time series exploration, I have a very trivial doubt.

In a Moving average model, where is the error term coming from. What is being subtracted from each value to get these errors, is it the first value in the series or any expected value?

For instance let's take an MA(1) model - `xt=μ+wt+θ1wt−1`; For `x1` what are `w1` and `w0`.

Answer (score 1):

An MA model assumes that you have a stationary process that bounces around the mean value μ

From this link (https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/48/):

"wt are identically, independently distributed, each with a normal distribution having mean 0 and the same variance."

So think of it like this.  Your prediction of Xt is the sum of three components.  First, you have the mean (μ).  The model is always trying to revert to this mean over the long run.  The second component (wt) is a white noise error term.  Since whatever process you are modeling (stock prices, temperatures in Antartica, etc.) isn't just a straight horizontal line, you need this term to represent the randomness in the data.  The third term (θ1 * wt−1) is your mean reversion parameter multiplied by the amount you deviated from the mean in the prior period.

For example, say that your mean is 10, and your time series is 10, 10, 10, 20, 15, 10, etc... for T=1, 2, 3... We assume that θ1=0.5.  When the time series jumps to 20 at T=4, your formula takes the form

Xt = μ + wt + θ1 * wt−1

(20 = 10 + 10 + 0.5 * 0)

where wt is the shock of 10, and the 3rd term is 0, as there was no shock in the prior period.

When T=5, your equation now takes the form

Xt = μ + wt + θ1 * wt−1

(15 = 10 + 0 + 0.5 * 10)

where wt-1 is now the 10 deviation from the prior time period and there is no further random shock in this period.

In T=6, the shock has worked itself through and the series has reverted to its mean.

Comment: A question: on T = 5, isn't the wt term 5 instead of 0? Since the mean is 10 but the value is 15, shouldn't wt be equal to 5?